# How to make a linux to run 2 applications and wifi?

Tags: linux

I want to run linux on a light computer to remote in, I'll use parsec to connect to my powerful pc and VirtualHere for usb passtrough, I'll also use wifi to connect it

Requirements (ideally)

- run parsec on launch
- run VirtualHere (server) in background
- no desktop/taskbar
- connecting to wifi with the wifi from the motherboard (Gigabyte B450 I AORUS PRO WIFI Mini ITX AM4 Motherboard

To clarify, the computer running this will be dedicated to being connect 100% of the time to the other computer via parsec
You can think of it as like a Shadow Box but custom made and connecting to a pc I already have (note the new revision of the shadow box is called the "shadow ghost")

Thanks for you time already

Comment: What was your question?  Have you read a Linux From Scratch guide?

Comment: I wanted to know if there was an easier way than Linux From Scratch

Comment: Sure, practically any Linux distribution around will do everything you want, once you install your couple programs and add a startup script or two.  But you wrote that you wanted to make your own.